# Is jQuery(userInput) "safe" for end-users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I'm developing a little jQuery selector game. Essentially, you're given some HTML code, and you have to write the jQuery selector to select the highlighted item.

For example, say you have:

```
<body>
  <p id="winner">Select this paragraph</p>
  <p> But not this one </p>
</body>
```

And one of the correct selectors would be $('#winner')

I currently plan on grabbing the string within the "$(' ... ') " (where the ...'s are) and doing something like this:

```
var userInput = ...
var userSelectedItems = new Array();
userSelectedItems = $(userInput)

// Check if userSelectedItems == the array of elements supposed to be selected
// Change screen to green and allow users to press enter and continue to next challenge.
```

Now, I know that if you allow users to directly enter some PHP or something, all sorts of bad things can happen, but is there anything with essentially allowing users to enter/execute this kind of javascript command? If so, how do you propose I get around this situation. I'd really enjoy making this educational game, so any help is greatly appreciated. I can't really see any way it could be dangerous because it's all run on the client's computer right..? I don't know though, maybe I'm missing something

Thanks

Comment: just fyi any modern browser lets you run arbitrary javascript on any site. Hit F12 and go to the console. ;p

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times before. There might be some leads searching for "eval javascript". However, it would take a little bit of work to make jQuery(input) do something besides "not work"; most normal users would never even run into such a case.

Comment: Re `userSelectedItems = $(userInput)`: I'd do a pre-check first that jQuery won't be treating the input as an HTML string rather than as a selector. (Since the `$` function is overloaded in about eight ways, and does different things depending on what you feed it, including doing different things depending on the **content** of the string you give it. E.g., `$("#foo")` is a lookup, `$("<div>")` creates a `div`. Epic API design fail, but we all make mistakes.) The easiest way to do that is to lift jQuery's code that makes that decision.

Comment: FWIW, I can run any jQuery I want on your page with Firebug or the Console in Chrome. So, I wouldn't be too concerned with it.

Comment: +1 what TJ said. Whether being able to create `$('<script>')` constitutes a vulnerability or not in your context, I'd suggest you want to use a call that explicitly matches a selector and has no other  sneaky function. eg. `$('body').find(userInput)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything on the client-side is always susceptible to changes done by the end-user.

However, if you aren't saving anything information to a database and there aren't any competitive conditions with regards to this game, I would not worry about any security issues that may arise. You can always sanitize client input within your own Javascript to ensure that non-technical users may not change game states during the process.

Answer (score 3):

Security problems may arise if you allow users to use other users' Javascript, however if the only person who is executing code is the person who is entering it, then you should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different than Javascript, the only vulnerability would be if someone was able to inject some code into your app or database which in result displays the content served on your web server.  As long as your app is protected against XSS and SQL Injections, you should be fine, it would be the same concept.